# Explicitly writing using(...) { ... } or hiding it?

Tags: c#, design, design-patterns

Today I had a discussion with our architect about writing using statements in WorkUnits.

Lets assume we have a PersonWorkUnit with methods:

```
public class PersonWorkUnit 
{    
    private IContextFactory contextFactory;
    private IRepositoryFactory repositoryFactory;

    public PersonWorkUnit(IContextFactory contextFactory, IRepositoryFactory repositoryFactory)
    {
        this.contextFactory = contextFactory;
        this.repositoryFactory = repositoryFactory;
    }

    public Person Get(int id) 
    {
         using(var context = this.contextFactory.Create<IPersonContext>())
         {
              var personRepo = this.repositoryFactory.Create<IPersonRepository>(context);
              return personRepo.Get(id);
         }
    }
}
```

What he doesn't like is, that we have to write the `using(var context = this.contextFactory.Create<IPersonContext>()) { var personRepo = this.repositoryFactory.Create<IPersonRepository>(context);` in every method of the WorkUnit.

My opinion is, that it is good to write (and read) it in every method because you can see explicitly the lifetime of the context and what is done during, or before/after the context. And if you have a usecases where you need multiple repositories.

His opinion is, that it's bad to "duplicate" this code in every method of the class and wants to "hide" it in a method-level-aspect (attribute).

What is your opinion on this topic?

I'm looking forward for insights and reasons/advantages/disadvantages for the solutions.

Thanks in advance

**Edit:** To answer some questions

- What is a context?
  With context I mean an entity framework DbContext
- Why have a ContextFactory?
  I want to have a factory so I don't have `new PersonContext()` and I can mock the DbContext in acceptance tests with an InMemoryDbContext
- What is a repository?
  Repositories (and repositories only) are responsible for accessing the database (DbContexts)
- What is a workunit?
  In WorkUnits we have methods that correspond to use cases. A use case could need multiple (different) repositories. In a WorkUnit method there could be done more than only a call to a repository... the example above is simplified
- Why not use the ContextFactory in repositories?
  Because some use cases require multiple repositories and I want them to use the same context, so that if something fails, the whole transaction is rolled back

Comment: The code does look odd. with the multiple layers of wrapping and only doing one thing in the method.

Comment: Do you handle transactions ? If so the pattern you're using seems unlikely able to do so (and if it does, it really don't like it, so that could be consider as a code smell)

Comment: @Walfrat Entity Framework handles transactions itself... if you open a new DbContext and call .SaveChanges() on it, it creates a transaction itself

Comment: @Walfrat what exactly do you consider a code smell? And what do you propose to change?

Comment: I don't really know entity framework, so what I mean by handling transaction, is, if I call two of your methods that performs writes, will they be part of the same transaction ? If so it could be usefull to add it in your question, because without knowing it that code seems to handle every call separately, or is that it's on a purpose ? A workUnit represent a transaction independant frm another work unit ?

Comment: Is it intentional that `Person` exists beyond the context that created it? It doesn't seem very transactional to have one context to create `Person` and another to save the changes

Comment: @xeraphim: You've misunderstood Walfrat, I think. Suppose we're looking at `public void AddToDatabase(Person person)`, which creates a new context in the method body, similar to your `Get()` method. How could you use this method to add **two people** in a **single transaction**? You can't, because each time you call `AddToDatabase()`, you create a new context (and therefore a new transaction).

Comment: @Flater If I have a method with the signature `AddToDatabase(Person person)` I really only want to add one person. If I want to add multiple persons in the same transaction, I'd have an overload `AddToDatabase(ICollection<Person> persons)` that opens a context, initializes the personrepository with the context and adds the persons in a foreach via the repository...

Comment: @xeraphim: `AddToDatabase(ICollection<Person> persons)` works for multiple entities of the same type, but what if you want to add entities of varying types in the same transaction? You'd very quickly end up with a ton of methods, one for every combination of entity types you want to add (and that's not even considering relations!). The UnitOfWork pattern solves this problem by having repositories work independently from a transaction (multiple repositories use the same parametrized transaction), as opposed to having repositories create their own transactions whenever they want to.

Comment: @Flater I'm sorry, I'm not sure if I understand it right... in my code the context is injected into the repository, the repository aren't creating any contexts / transactions. If I have multiple entities of different types, I'd have an according method in the WorkUnit that creates the context and initializes multiple repositories with the same context.

Comment: @xeraphim: I'm struggling to see the benefit of your approach here. You'll need to create a custom method for every combination of objects you want to use, and that seems counterproductive. You're essentially working with a UnitOfWork(-like?) pattern under the hood, but are then wrapping it in a way that it (externally) looks like a regular repository? Or am I misunderstanding the intention of your code here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the way you describe your code, it sounds like `PersonWorkUnit` has a set of methods that all follow the follow format:

```
public SomeType Foo(...) 
{
    using(var context = this.contextFactory.Create<IPersonContext>())
    {
        var personRepo = this.repositoryFactory.Create<IPersonRepository>(context);
        // do something with personRepo to create SomeType instance
        // return SomeType
    }
}
```

If that is the case, then just use delegates to create a single method that does everything bar the commented lines, and supply the latter via a `Func<>`:

```
public Person Get(int id) => ProcessPersonRepo(p => p.Get(id));

private T ProcessPersonRepo<T>(Func<IPersonRepository, T> specificBehaviour) 
{
    using(var context = contextFactory.Create<IPersonContext>())
    {
        var personRepo = repositoryFactory.Create<IPersonRepository>(context);
        return specificBehaviour(personRepo);
    }
}
```

Comment: You may also want an `Action<IPersonRepository>` overload, if `T` would otherwise be `void`

Comment: This is the recommended way whenever you wish to wrap an unknown function with known code.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps Its just your example but this code just looks odd to me. a code smell if you will.

You have four objects which have possible control of the db connection

- The context factory
- The repository
- The work unit
- The context itself

I can see why you might want all these, but its quite a complex setup.

I'm sure your example is deliberately kept short, but it does raise some questions about possible ways to simplify the code.

- If your work unit methods mirror the repositories, why have them at all? Just call the repository.
- Could the context factory not be part of the repository? Perhaps use a connection string constructor.
- What value is added by creating a new repository on each call? Could you not simply inject the repository?
- If your Work Unit methods are bigger than the example, would Transaction Scope be an alternative method of controling the unit?

If you Real Life code justifies the use of all four objects and each has a clear responsibility, then:

Yes, its good practice to dispose of the context after use and...

No, I would say moving the using block to an Aspect Orientated Attribute just throws another complexity into an already complex scenario and obfuscates rather than simplifies the code.

Comment: Hi @Ewan thanks for your answer, I've added some insights to the original question to clarify things

Comment: no prob. Personally I would stick with one repo per db, have it manage the context and use transaction scope. But I know other people use your pattern, I don't see a problem with it

Answer (score -2):

Dealing with context and repository objects are data access level concerns and should be separated from your business objects which is what PersonWorkUnit appears to be. You should have a data access class that only handles using the context and repository. this would make your business code simpler by only having something like `dataGetter.GetPerson(Id);` in your get method. If you know the person you need at creation of the PersonWorkUnit you could even move this call to the constructor which will simplify the code that calls PersonWorkUnit as well. All the ugly boiler plate code is then in dataGetter where it can be ignored for the most part.

The goal of this setup is to maintain separation of concerns so your business logic doesn't have to deal with infrastructure logic, and it also allows you to follow the open closed principle. with your example design PersonWorkUnit must change if data access rules change and if business rules about person change. By having a dataGetter class that returns a person, the only reason for PersonWorkUnit to change is because the business logic changes.